# Cocoa Singleton conventions

Tags: cocoa, singleton

Cocoa is full of singletons.  Is there a logical/conventional difference between when the Cocoa APIs use

```
NSSingletonObject *so = [NSSingletonObject defaultSingleton];
```

versus

```
NSSingletonObject *so = [NSSingletonObject sharedSingleton];
```

?

Not a huge thing, but I don't really see why sometimes one is used versus the other.

Comment: Which Classes are you thinking of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it tends to be that if it is a true singleton (such as [NSApplication](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSApplication/sharedApplication)) that you are using, then the `-[JKFoo sharedFoo]` convention is followed.  If on the other hand the class provides access to a default instance but you can still create other instances (for example [NSNotificationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotificationQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNotificationQueue/defaultQueue) or [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) then the `-[JKBar defaultBar]` convention is used.

Side note: if you are implementing a few of your own Cocoa singletons, then there is a [useful OpenSource header](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMObjectSingleton.h) you might want to take a look at :)

[edit: an even better singleton solution using GCD was pointed out by Mike Ash on his [blog](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-10-02-care-and-feeding-of-singletons.html)]

Comment: Regarding implementing your own singleton, there are many recepies on the web for implementing a *true* singleton in Cocoa, but for the most part Objective-C handles things by convention rather than stricture. Don't waste your time writing a bullet-proof singleton unless your code will be used by many outside devs. If you document a class as being a singleton, Objective-C style generally says that's engough...if you use it as a non-singleton, that's your problem.

Comment: NSApplication isn't a singlton. Nor NSNotificationCenter or NSFileManager. I'm not sure i can think of a singleton in Cocoa.

Comment: @mustlSignUp: OK, if you're being pedantic, you are right, but I think most people would refer to these classes as singletons as do Apple - http://gemma.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW66.